# Can Swift init() returns previously created object?

Tags: swift, initialization, rx-swift

I use RxSwift. This func returns Observable

```
func getDeviceInfo(_ deviceId: Int) -> Observable<DeviceInfo> {
    return Observable.create { o in
        self.getInfo(deviceId, onSuccess: { data in
            o.onNext(data)
            o.onCompleted()
        }, onFail: { error in
            o.onError(error)
        })
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

then I subscribe to it

```
repository.getDeviceInfo(deviceId)
            .subscribe(onNext: { (info) in 
                print("onNext")
            }, onError: { (error) in
                print("onError")
            }, onCompleted: {
                print("onCompleted")
            }, onDisposed: {
                print("onDisposed")
            })
```

First time I get true result. But when I call subscribe() second time, third and etc. no subscribe's callbacks are called (onNext, onError, onCompleted, onDisposed).
After debug I found that o.onNext(data), o.onCompleted() in getDeviceInfo() are called but subscribe's callbacks don't receive any data. 
I debugged the next line in Create.swift file inside RxSwift

```
let sink = AnonymousObservableSink(observer: observer, cancel: cancel)
```

AnonymousObservableSink class some code, it's not Singelton:

```
final fileprivate class AnonymousObservableSink<O: ObserverType> : Sink<O>, ObserverType {

override init(observer: O, cancel: Cancelable) {
    super.init(observer: observer, cancel: cancel)
}
```

but each time the reference `let sink` was the same. So can init() func returns early created object sometimes?

Comment: sink is declared as a constant, its value cannot be changed once it has been set, try changing sink to a variable

Comment: sink is declared inside RxSwift library and created every time I call subscribe(), so I should get the new instance of class.

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to override a class marked as final? This prevents Swift from overriding any properties and methods inside that class

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when I call subscribe() second time." Remember, once an Observable emits a completed or error it shuts down and cannot emit any more values.

Comment: I know this. In other words: when I call func ( getDeviceInfo() ) with subscribe() code second time. Also I found that this problem happens when I add the getDeviceInfo() subscription to CompositeDisposable that holds references to early created subscriptions